# Trigger a function (code) at particular time

Tags: android

I have created a small app, but I want it to execute automatically at a particular time. The time must be entered by the user.

For example : 
If my activity is, to start a particular game and I enter 5:30pm as the time, it should run that game at 5:30pm automatically, even if I close the application after I entered time.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an alarm and a broadcast reciever for it, put the intent for this in the Android Manifest

Take a look at http://blog.mikesir87.io/2013/04/android-creating-an-alarm-with-alarmmanager/

Just set the alarms for a week in advanced.

---

For the touch thing try this replace:

```
Button stopAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm);
        stopAlarm.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                finish();
                return false;
            }
        });
```

With

```
Button stopAlarm = (Button) findViewById(R.id.stopAlarm);
        stopAlarm.setOnClickListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View arg0) {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                finish();
            }
        });
```

The reason we dont need to use arg0 or arg1 is that we already know where the touch or click is coming from, in the situation where you have a activity wide click listener (so the activity implements onClickListener) you would use something like this:

```
        @Override
        public void onClick(View arg0) {
            switch(arg0){
                  case R.id.id1:
                  //Do what you want here
                  break;
                  case R.id.id2:
                  //Do what you want here
                  break;
                  default:
                  //Do default stuff
                  break;
            }
        }
```

---

To my understanding however I believe you don't need any of this stuff however correct? You just want your activity to run at these times right?

So if I am correct you just need to do this:

```
public class AlarmReceiverActivity extends Activity {

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.alarm);

        //Do what you want here
        //This is now your activity to play with :D
    }

}
```

Comment: I guess I have at least a direction to work. I'll let you know when I'm successful. Thanks.

Comment: No problem, sorry I can't give you code, I have done this in the past but I have no idea where the project files are

Comment: I am implementing the alarm clock from the link you gave...It gives me error in line 14 of alarmclockActivity. It says onTouchListner can't be resolved to a type. 
Nor i can undrestand why arguments arg0 and arg1 are left as it is..

Comment: `stopAlarm.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
            public boolean onTouch(View arg0, MotionEvent arg1) {
                mMediaPlayer.stop();
                finish();
                return false;`
I'm talking about this part..

Comment: Yep I figured that, look at my answer now :)

Comment: I don't have any raw folder...where am i suppose to get the sound?
Its working but when i'm running it...nothing is happening. just the hello screen. where shud i give the refrence to sound?

Comment: getAlarmUri() should be getting the default alarm file for you as part of the android OS, its part of the API's (alarms and notifications) you shouldn't need a sound file. Is your alarm sound on? Or phone on silent? Possibilities

Comment: Hmm, do you want to try it on a physical device?